# Let $P(z)=1+2z+3z^2+\cdots+nz^{n-1}$. Use the Gauss-Lucas theorem to show that all roots of this polynomial are in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

> Let $P(z)=1+2z+3z^2+\cdots+nz^{n-1}$. Use the Gauss-Lucas theorem to show that all roots of this polynomial are in the unit disk.

I am able to show this directly by considering $(1-z)P(z)$ and seeing that if $w$ is root of $P(z)$ then $w$ is a root of $(1-z)P(z)$ and then seeing that if $|w|>1$, we get a contradiction.

But I am not sure how to use the Gauss-Lucas theorem to show this. The Gauss-Lucas theorem says: Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial. If $p'(w_0)=0$, then $w_0$ lies in the convex hull of the zeros of $p(z)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$P(z) = \frac{d}{dz}(z^n+z^{n-1}+\cdots + z+1)$

$Q(z) = z^n+z^{n-1}+\cdots + z+1 = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$

The zeros of $Q$ lie obviously on the unit disk.

So, the zeros of $P$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $Q$, hence also in the unit disc.

Comment: How does this show the zeros of $P$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $Q$?

Comment: This is that what the Gauss-Lucas theorem says. According to your question you are supposed to apply this theorem to show that the zeros of $P$ lie in the unit disc. So, the only thing to show is that $P$ is the derivative of a polynomial the zeros of which lie in the unit disc.

Comment: I think you may have an error. The zeros of $Q$ in the unit disk does not imply the zeros of $Q'=P$ lie in the unit disk.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: Yes, the zeros of $p'$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $p$. That is not what you have.

Comment: $P = Q'$, zeros of $Q$ lie in the unit disc (which is convex). Gauss-Lucas says: Zeros of $Q'=P$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $Q$.